# Как удалить все дубликаты строк в txt файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл в котором 570.000 строк и некоторые из них дублируются. 
Мне необходимо удалить все дубликаты и оставить 1 вариант строки, 
а так же вывести количество удалённых строк в консоль.
Как это можно реализовать с версией Python 3.8.5 ?

Comment: Что вызывает затруднения в решении данной задачи? Что не работает в вашем коде?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Я тупо хз как это сделать..

Comment: Есть отступи?если нет то не знаю как.

Comment: @ІванШнір Да построчная запись:
1
2
3
и тд с каждой новой строки

Comment: Можете ли вы скинуть сам файл?

Comment: Идите по строкам. Добавляйте строки в `set`. Если очередная строка уже была в `set`, то не пишите её в выходной файл и увеличьте счётчик удалённых строк. Всё.

Comment: @CrazyElf А что такое "set" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот готовый код, просто поменяйте под себя его.

```
name_file = "Ваше имя файла.txt"
f = open(name_file,'r').read()
total = f.split('\n')
f = f.split('\n')
f = set(f)
print(f)
print(len(total) - len(f),'всего удалённых строк')
```